# Adding a line on a graph in r

Tags: r

Based on the following data, I want to plot

```
m <- 10000
x <- runif(m,-1,1)
a0 <- 0; a1 <- -4.46; a2 <- 1.6; a3 <- -4.63
```

two variables `p1.at.x` and `p0.at.x`, defined below, against `x`.

```
p0.at.x <- numeric(0) 
p1.at.x <- numeric(0)               
for(i in 1:m) {
  p0.at.x[i] <- a0 +(a1*x[i]) + (a2*((1.5*(x[i]**2))-0.5)) + (a3*((2.5*(x[i]**3))-(1.5*x[i])))
  p1.at.x[i] <- 16 -(40.4*x[i]) + (31*((1.5*(x[i]** 2))-0.5 ))-(18.3*((2.5*(x[i]**3))-(1.5*x[i])))
}
```

I tried with the following:

```
plot(x, p1.at.x, col="red")        
lines(x, p0.at.x, col="blue")
```

but I could not see the line for `p0.at.x` on the graph. When I plot them individually, they have a similar shape, only differ in range. May somebody suggest me what went wrong?

Comment: What are the values of a0, a1, a2 and a3?

Comment: Without knowing those values its hard to diagnose but I am almost sure its because the two ranges for the x-axis do not coincide with one another.

Comment: What all of the answers/comments are implicitly telling you is that once a device window is created, it isn't automatically resized if you then call functions like `lines` or `points`. The device window will remain the "optimal" size for whatever data was originally plotted. So either need to know the max extent of _all_ your data up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the right ylim:

```
plot(x, p1.at.x, col="red",ylab='p',ylim=range(p0.at.x,p1.at.x))   
par(new=TRUE)  
plot(x, p0.at.x, col="blue",ylab='p', ylim=range(p0.at.x,p1.at.x))
```

If they differ in range, then you aren't seeing the second because it's out of the window of the first plot, so you have to account for its presence when you open the plot.

[image]

Alternatively:

```
plot(x, p1.at.x, col="red",ylab='p',ylim=range(p0.at.x,p1.at.x))    
points(x, p0.at.x, col="blue",ylab='p', ylim=range(p0.at.x,p1.at.x))
```

Comment: @DiscreteCircle your codes, as gave me a plot where the line is no a line. It is some image

Comment: I just corrected it; lines(...) wasn't working well with your data.

Comment: I would have imagined that the call would have been: `plot(... , ylim=range(c(p0.at.x,p1.at.x)))` but I guess the authors were kinder than I realized.

Comment: I believe `range` is in base, and with functions such as `max` and `min`, it is part of the S4 'Summary' group generic and therefore uses `( ..., na.rm)`. Functions such as `median`, in the `stats` package, need to specify one argument only, as they use `(x,na.rm)` as arguments.